# Не могу обновить данные в таблице Django?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Есть сайт, где я вывожу в цикле элементы таблицы таким образом:

```
    <ul>
        {% for topic in topics %}
                <li><a href="/topic/{{ topic.pk }}">{{ topic.subject}}<br /> 
                { topic.text}}</a></li> 
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Я хочу добавить около каждого элемента кнопку, при нажатии которой topic.subject, topic.text данной **конкретной** ячейки будут добавляться в другую раннее созданную таблицу.
Используя только Django при этом.

Можно вызывать функцию во `views.py` по нажатию кнопки, но как передать в неё subject u text? Может, можно как-то построить пост-запрос, используя используя эти данные. У меня пока ничего не вышло.

Всем заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нужно добавлять в другую таблицу на этой же странице без её перезагрузки? Тогда нужно это делать полностью на клиентской стороны на js.

Comment: Не обязательно. Можно редиректить на другую страницу, если требуется. Нужен метод без js, может даже и костыльный, ибо сейчас в нём разбираться времени нет. Или ты можешь рассказать, как сделать это, используя java script.

Comment: `{{ topic.text}}` . А так, да, тут js + ajax нужен, скорее всего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу сам, мужики. Сделал не без помощи одного хорошего разработчика.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{topic.pk}}">
```

такой или подобный код засовываем в цикл. А после всего списка делаем кнопку с `input type="submit"`. Весь цикл и кнопку оборачиваем в `<form> ... </form>`. После чего **POST**-запросом по нажатию отправляем отмеченные элементы в функцию во `views.py`. А там уже можно с ними делать что угодно.

Такие дела.